# Scientist who studies electromagnetism/electromagnetics?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a scientist who specializes in electromagnetism/electromagnetics? I don't even know if there is a specific word for this, but am curious to know. The only thing I can come up with is "electromagnetic specialist" or something like that; but that isn't a very "scientific" word.

Comment: Well, the general area of his specialty would be "physics".  But there are many different specialties in the area of electromagnetism, from motor design to astrophysics, so it would be hard to nail down things any further without knowing more about this scientist.

Comment: Currently one could say *accelerator physicist*.  Please give us the context where you need the word, and a sample sentence.

Comment: No, definitely not accelerator physicist. I may have not given enough depth to my description, but I think Cerberus has already answered my question. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: *The above comment is @aparente001

Comment: @Hot Licks: Yes, I do think that my description may be kind of watered down, so sorry about that. But the question has been answered, so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Both [electromagnetist](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&hl=en&tbm=bks&q=electromagnetist&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinlPqvx5bUAhUWOsAKHZ2wATMQvgUIJSgB&biw=1798&bih=926&dpr=1) and [electromagnetician](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&hl=en&tbm=bks&q=electromagnetician&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTuYmlx5bUAhWpKsAKHYy5Co4QvgUIJSgB&biw=1798&bih=926&dpr=1) have been used by some authors. The latter word, **electromagnetician**, seems to be used more frequently; while it does have an old-fashioned ring to it, it is a legitimate word.

Comment: That is exactly the sort of word I am looking for, thank you. I was wondering because I am looking to specialize in electromagnetics and was curious to know the term, if any existed, for such a specialist.